# Alternative for setting AWS environment variables using mockito

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, mockito

I have a method in a class, where internally calls `AmazonS3Client.java` in which `AwsCredetialsProvider.getCredentials()` is been called. For that I need to set `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` in my test class. Setting those values in Environment Variables are not allowed in my project.

I have tried to Mock `AWSCredentialsProvider`, and `AWSCredentials` and used stubbing to return credentials. But it is throwing the following error:

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:131)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3648)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3607)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:600)
```

Even I have tried setting those values using `MockEnvironment`, `ConfigurationProperties` too. But nothing happened.

So, is there any possible way to mock these credential values?

I am using `MockitoJRunner`. So, I cannot change it to Powermockito only for one method.

**Edited:**
I want to fetch the files from S3 by calling `listObjects()`. This is where I am facing the issue as it needs AWS credentials to fetch.

All the method callings are project specified where internally calling predefined classes and methods.

Comment: Please add the code of your unit test.

Answer (score 0):

Consider mocking `AmazonS3Client` class instead of something it uses internally. If some day AWS library will get an update that changes `AmazonS3Client` internals then you might have your tests broken.

```
AmazonS3Client amazonClient = Mockito.mock(AmazonS3Client.class);
```

And then set the object to be returned

```
Mockito.doReturn(objListing).when(amazonClient).listObjects(bucketName);
```

Comment: Still getting the same exception.. :(